# IE8/Javascript conflicts? IE8 freezing across site in development - Javascript list included

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer, optimization, freeze

We are currently updating our website with redesign. However, the site is freezing in Windows XP / IE 8, but our development team is not sure why. The version of IE8 is 8.0.6001.18702.

Here is the JavaScript used across the site in the header. Are there any known conflicts which could be freezing IE8?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/jquery.min.js?D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/misc/drupal.js?D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer" src="/sites/all/modules/admin_menu/admin_menu.js?D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/libraries/colorbox/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js?D"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/modules/colorbox/js/colorbox.js?D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/modules/colorbox/styles/default/colorbox_default_style.js?D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/modules/nice_menus/superfish/js/superfish.js?D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/modules/nice_menus/superfish/js/jquery.bgiframe.min.js?D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/modules/nice_menus/nice_menus.js?D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/libraries/qtip//jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js?D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/modules/qtip/js/qtip.js?D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/modules/spamspan/spamspan.compressed.js?D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/modules/thickbox/thickbox.js?D"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/modules/views_slideshow/js/views_slideshow.js?D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/modules/custom/rra_helper/js/rra_helper.js?D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/modules/nodequeue/nodequeue.js?D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/modules/ctools/js/ajax-responder.js?D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/modules/boxes/boxes.js?D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/modules/views/js/base.js?D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/modules/views/js/ajax_view.js?D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/modules/jquery_update/replace/jquery.form.js?D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/themes/chi/js/jquery.selectbox/jquery.selectBox.min.js?D"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/themes/chi/scripts.js?D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/themes/chi/jquery.dataTables.js?D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/themes/chi/js/menutodropdown.js?D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/themes/chi/js/jquery.tipsy.js?D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/modules/text_resize/jquery.cookie.js?D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sites/all/modules/text_resize/text_resize.js?D"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, { "basePath": "/", "admin_menu": { "margin_top": 1, "tweak_tabs": 1 }, "colorbox": { "transition": "elastic", "speed": 350, "opacity": "0.85", "slideshow": false, "slideshowAuto": false, "slideshowSpeed": 2500, "slideshowStart": "", "slideshowStop": "", "current": "{current} of {total}", "previous": "« Prev", "next": "Next »", "close": "Close", "overlayClose": true, "maxWidth": "100%", "maxHeight": "100%" }, "nice_menus_options": { "delay": "100", "speed": "fast" }, "qtip": { "target_position": "topRight", "tooltip_position": "bottomLeft", "show_speech_bubble_tip": true, "show_speech_bubble_tip_side": false, "color": "blue", "border_radius": "3", "border_width": "3", "show_event_type": "mouseover", "hide_event_type": "mouseout", "show_solo": true }, "spamspan": { "m": "spamspan", "u": "u", "d": "d", "h": "h", "t": "t" }, "thickbox": { "close": "Close", "next": "Next \x3e", "prev": "\x3c Prev", "esc_key": "or Esc Key", "next_close": "Next / Close on last", "image_count": "Image !current of !total" }, "getQ": "node/3", "views": { "ajax_path": "/views/ajax", "ajaxViews": { "views_dom_id:4b8e8b3a493bcb7f11628f340513d203": { "view_name": "related_publications", "view_display_id": "block_1", "view_args": "3", "view_path": "node/3", "view_base_path": "case-studies-all", "view_dom_id": "4b8e8b3a493bcb7f11628f340513d203", "pager_element": 0 } } } });
//--><!]]>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
var text_resize_scope = "content";
    var text_resize_minimum = "10";
    var text_resize_maximum = "25";
    var text_resize_line_height_allow = 0;
    var text_resize_line_height_min = "16";
    var text_resize_line_height_max = "36";
//--><!]]>
</script>
```

Comment: It might be worth noting here that there is a good case for using a javascript loader or using more defer attributes unless these are absolutely necessary to load BEFORE the rest of the page loads OR try moving all of these to the bottom of the page before the closing </body> tag and then comparing the performance on IE8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, @MyStream is correct -- you should consider using a JS library manager. I'd suggest you use Require.JS or something like that.

Secondly, when a browser freezes like the way you're describing, its often because of an infinite loop or just excessive looping occurring in a script, somewhere.

To begin solving your problem, I recommend that you not load a few of the files, here and there in an attempt to determine exactly which file is causing the slowdown. Once you find the culprit, go through and determine what code is the problem, and then fix it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your insights (!), I have passed them on to begin troubleshooting.